# R: Identify ID in dataframe where group assignment changes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with three columns: an ID and two group assignments to which each ID belongs. The group assignments in the the two cluster columns are almost the same for all IDs except for a few. However, the group assignment code changes, but the IDs still belong to the same group. I would like to identify the ID whose group assignment changes between the two cluster columns.

In the example data below, I would like to identify ID 79 which belongs to group 68 in column "cluster.n1" and to group 62 in column "cluster.cur". On the other hand, the IDs 82 and 83 belong to group 70 in "cluster.n1" and to group 69 in "cluster.cur". But they are still in the same group.

This is my data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
120, 121), cluster.n1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 13L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 32L, 44L, 47L, 48L, 43L, 49L, 15L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 54L, 70L, 70L, 35L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
74L, 73L, 75L, 76L, 68L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
31L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 
95L, 95L, 91L, 96L, 92L, 95L, 97L, 98L), cluster.cur = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 13L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 32L, 44L, 
47L, 48L, 43L, 49L, 15L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 62L, 68L, 54L, 
69L, 69L, 35L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 72L, 74L, 75L, 67L, 76L, 77L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 31L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
89L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 90L, 95L, 91L, 94L, 96L, 
97L)), row.names = c(NA, -121L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why IDs 82, 83, ... are in the same group. What rule is this based on? .. I suppose 
`with(mydata, ID[which(cluster.n1!=cluster.cur)])` is not what you want?

Comment: These are the results of a clustering, n1 is clustered to 98 groups, cur to 97 groups. Almost all the group assignments remain the same, but the group id shifts. I want to identify which original IDs have changed their group assignment.